# Which items should I buy (or not) in Arena?

Tags: smite

What are staples (or faux pas) for every role and per role?
If this question is too broad, it can be split per role, specializing this one and then I'd just make new questions for the other roles.

Comment: As both of our answers are pretty large and cover 2 different areas (yours leans more towards comp play while mine is more generalized... I only play Arena and those are the builds I notice in casual play) I begin to feel like this a bit too broad.

Comment: I only play Arena too. If you deeply insist, I'll either make a new question or modify the current question to ask something expecting an answer more along the lines of what/how I've answered.

Answer (score 2):

I researched so much, I've decided to just post what I've noted as an answer.

The following data were collected according to as many screenshots as I could capture from the $10K Alienware Arena Cup (which took place 19 April 2014, which is important because the developers change items often). Lesser-known teams and names were given less weight. Items are usually enumerated in a meaningful order.

- As with any other game-mode, [Ta](http://smite.gamepedia.com/Warrior_Tabi)[bi](http://smite.gamepedia.com/Ninja_Tabi) are staples for physical characters and [Sho](http://smite.gamepedia.com/Shoes_of_the_Magi)[es](http://smite.gamepedia.com/Shoes_of_Focus) for magical characters.
- Items that build stacks are discouraged.
- Common actives are [Heavenly Agility, Greater Sprint](http://smite.gamepedia.com/Sprint), [Curses](http://smite.gamepedia.com/Creeping_Curse), Greater [Aegis](http://smite.gamepedia.com/Aegis_Amulet), [Greater Purification Beads](http://smite.gamepedia.com/Purification_Beads), and [Greater Blink](http://smite.gamepedia.com/Blink).
- [Magi's Blessing](http://smite.gamepedia.com/Magi%27s_Blessing) was common for all roles.
- [Hide of the Urchin](http://smite.gamepedia.com/Hide_of_the_Urchin) is popular for anyone but [Mages](http://smite.gamepedia.com/Mage).
- Physical characters usually get [Warrior Tabi](http://smite.gamepedia.com/Warrior_Tabi), [Jotunn's Wrath](http://smite.gamepedia.com/Jotunn%27s_Wrath), and [Titan's Bane](http://smite.gamepedia.com/Titan%27s_Bane). Other items (in descending order of popularity) include [Deathbringer](http://smite.gamepedia.com/Deathbringer), [Rage](http://smite.gamepedia.com/Rage), [Qin's Sais](http://smite.gamepedia.com/Qin%27s_Sais), [Shifter's Shield](http://smite.gamepedia.com/Shifter%27s_Shield), and [Void Shield](http://smite.gamepedia.com/Void_Shield).
- [Warriors](http://smite.gamepedia.com/Warrior) (bruisers) don't pick purely offensive items other than [Jotunn's Wrath](http://smite.gamepedia.com/Jotunn%27s_Wrath), [Titan's Bane](http://smite.gamepedia.com/Titan%27s_Bane), and [Qin's Sais](http://smite.gamepedia.com/Qin%27s_Sais) ([Guan Yu](http://smite.gamepedia.com/Guan_Yu) gets not even this).
- As a sort of response to [Rapitor](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/47011/rapitor)'s [answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/173745/46216), I checked how many times [Ninja Tabi](http://smite.gamepedia.com/Ninja_Tabi) appeared and noted only three instances: [Anatoliy](http://tiermonster.com/p/AnatoLiy) as [Sun Wukong](http://smite.gamepedia.com/Sun_Wukong) in round 3 of Dignitas vs. COG Gaming, [GameHunter](http://tiermonster.com/p/Gamehunter) as [Tyr](http://smite.gamepedia.com/Tyr) in round 3 of TSM vs. Exposed, and [InfernalTwist](http://tiermonster.com/p/InFeRnAlTwist) as [Sun Wukong](http://smite.gamepedia.com/Sun_Wukong) in the first round of Rage vs. Dignitas. Otherwise, [Warrior Tabi](http://smite.gamepedia.com/Warrior_Tabi) was picked by an overwhelming majority.
- [Mages](http://smite.gamepedia.com/Mage) usually get [Shoes of the Magi](http://smite.gamepedia.com/Shoes_of_the_Magi), [Rod of Tahuti](http://smite.gamepedia.com/Rod_of_Tahuti), and [Obsidian Shard](http://smite.gamepedia.com/Obsidian_Shard). They often get defensive actives, like [Aegis](http://smite.gamepedia.com/Aegis_Amulet), [Beads](http://smite.gamepedia.com/Purification_Beads), and [Combat Blink](http://smite.gamepedia.com/Blink), but sometimes [Heavenly Agility or Greater Sprint](http://smite.gamepedia.com/Sprint). Other items (in descending order of popularity) include [Polynomicon](http://smite.gamepedia.com/Polynomicon), [Shoes of Focus](http://smite.gamepedia.com/Shoes_of_Focus), [Breastplate of Valor](http://smite.gamepedia.com/Breastplate_of_Valor), [Spear of the Magus](http://smite.gamepedia.com/Spear_of_the_Magus), [Bancroft's Talon](http://smite.gamepedia.com/Bancroft%27s_Talon), [Chronos' Pendant](http://smite.gamepedia.com/Chronos%27_Pendant), [Void Stone](http://smite.gamepedia.com/Void_Stone), and [Gem of Isolation](http://smite.gamepedia.com/Gem_of_Isolation) (seen on [Chang'e](http://smite.gamepedia.com/Chang%27e), [Poseidon](http://smite.gamepedia.com/Poseidon), and [Ao Kuang](http://smite.gamepedia.com/Ao_Kuang).
- [Guardians](http://smite.gamepedia.com/Guardian) (tanks) usually get [Sovereignty](http://smite.gamepedia.com/Sovereignty), [Shoes of Focus](http://smite.gamepedia.com/Shoes_of_Focus), and [Shell of Absorption](http://smite.gamepedia.com/Shell).
- [Chronos](http://smite.gamepedia.com/Chronos) commonly gets [Hastened Fatalis](http://smite.gamepedia.com/Hastened_Fatalis) and less commonly [Demonic Grip](http://smite.gamepedia.com/Demonic_Grip).
- [Freya](http://smite.gamepedia.com/Freya) commonly gets [Hastened Fatalis](http://smite.gamepedia.com/Hastened_Fatalis) and [Demonic Grip](http://smite.gamepedia.com/Demonic_Grip).
- [Vamana](http://smite.gamepedia.com/Vamana) commonly gets [Hastened Fatalis](http://smite.gamepedia.com/Hastened_Fatalis).
- [Demonic Grip](http://smite.gamepedia.com/Demonic_Grip) is common with [Freya](http://smite.gamepedia.com/Freya) but less common on [Chronos](http://smite.gamepedia.com/Chronos), [Poseidon](http://smite.gamepedia.com/Poseidon), and [Nu Wa](http://smite.gamepedia.com/Nu_Wa) (small sample size).
- Top Arena League player [Cee](http://www.reddit.com/user/CeeVeee)[Vee](http://account.hirezstudios.com/smitegame/stats.aspx?player=CeeVee) usually gets [Rod of Asclepius](http://smite.gamepedia.com/Rod_of_Asclepius) and [Heavenly Agility](http://smite.gamepedia.com/Sprint) as [Chang'e](http://smite.gamepedia.com/Chang%27e).
- [Greater Blink](http://smite.gamepedia.com/Blink) is common with [Ares](http://smite.gamepedia.com/Ares), [Athena](http://smite.gamepedia.com/Athena), [Bacchus](http://smite.gamepedia.com/Bacchus), [Chaac](http://smite.gamepedia.com/Chaac), [Geb](http://smite.gamepedia.com/Geb), [Hun Batz](http://smite.gamepedia.com/Hun_Batz), [Kumbhakarna](http://smite.gamepedia.com/Kumbhakarna), [Odin](http://smite.gamepedia.com/Odin), and [Tyr](http://smite.gamepedia.com/Tyr).
- Be mindful that some items may be good with other characters unmentioned, but I haven't mentioned them because the sample that I studied (Alienware Arena Cup teams) did not pick those characters, which hints at which characters that you think would go good with an item that I mentioned are not good characters for Arena.
- A new item to consider is [Ancile](http://smite.gamepedia.com/Ancile) for physical characters, though it is a stacking item (+5/+1, 60). It maxes out at +50 Physical Power and +15% Cooldown Reduction (and +50 Magical Protection).

Some URLs redundantly appear as multiple sources in the code. If someone could clean them or teach me how to (efficiently), I'd appreciate it.

Comment: "Items that build stacks are discouraged." What about the items that build stacks on minion kills, like the Warrior Sash?

Comment: You mean Warlock's Sash? Yes, even those. I think they're only considered viable if you are the dedicated laner and, at least  for stacks lost on death, good at not dying. For a sec, I thought your name was part of the comment.

Answer (score 1):

Something to note is that like any game mode and god, there is no end-all item build. You build what you need for the situation. They have extra tanky characters? use executioners. More mages? Stone of Gaia. ***All*** Items are viable and situational.

a few examples:

Warriors benefit much more from Ninja Tabi instead of Warrior (more cdr as warriors do more with their skills)

Mages like Ao go for stackable items (especially [Book of thoth](http://smite.gamepedia.com/Book_of_Thoth) because he has no trouble farming minions, even in crowds.

Guardians lean more towards CDR with  [Breastplate of valor](http://smite.gamepedia.com/Breastplate_of_Valor) and [Shoes of focus](http://smite.gamepedia.com/Shoes_of_Focus) as it lets them control the battlefield more often.

Hunters like swapping out an item for either fatalis or [Frostbound](http://smite.gamepedia.com/Frostbound_Hammer) to make the wide open area of arena more manageable in combat.

Assassins also go for movement speed and/or the Hunter-mentioned weapons as it lets them cover more ground and chase better, as arena doesn't have the flank/gank potential of say Conquest or Siege.

Much like any of the other game modes, there are core items that are for that god regardless of mode (like fatalis on Vama/Freya), but listing each and every 'core' for each god is far too much for an answer.